# Two parallel longtables, one on left pages, one on right pages

Tags: longtable, double-sided, parallel-texts

I have two very large, 3-page long longtables: table 1 with ancient texts and table 2 with modern translations. I would like to have them side-by-side on opposite pages, table 1 on left pages, table 2 on right pages.I have seen different questions on how to fit two longtables side by side on the same page (which would work fine if the texts were shorter), but I am at a loss on how to put them on opposite pages

```
   \documentclass[twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,paper=a4,fontsize=10pt]{scrreprt}
    \usepackage{longtable}
            
    \begin{document}

    %Table 1        
    \begin{longtable}{cp{3cm}p{4cm}p{4cm}}
    &\multicolumn{3}{c}{TEXTS}\\
    &&&\\
    a & Chinese & Sogdian  & Syriac \\
    & Chinese & Sogdian  & Syriac \\
    & Chinese & Sogdian  & Syriac \\
    b & Chinese & Sogdian  & Syriac \\
    & Chinese & Sogdian  & Syriac \\
    & [...] & [...]  & [...] \\
    \end{longtable}

    `%Table 2        
        \begin{longtable}{cp{3cm}p{4cm}p{4cm}}
        &\multicolumn{3}{c}{TRANSLATIONS}\\
        &&&\\
        a & English 1 & English 2 & English 3 \\
        & English 1 & English 2 & English 3 \\
        & English 1 & English 2 & English 3 \\
        b & English 1 & English 2 & English 3 \\
        & English 1 & English 2 & English 3 \\
        & [...] & [...]  & [...] \\
        \end{longtable}
                
            
                \end{document}
```

Comment: simplest would be to do each table as a separated document then in your main doc use `pdfpages` package or simply `\includegaphcs` with `[page=1]{tabA}`, `[page=1]{tabB}`, `[page=2]{tabA}`, `[page=2]{tabB}`, ...

Comment: Alas, longtable is not compatible with paracol.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I'm sure you intended that sentence in the other order to shift the implication of blame:-)

Comment: If you are sure of the final layout and table contents,  indeed the simplest solution is split  each longtable in three standard tabulars, then order the six tables in the correct sequence. It not an automatic solution, but it is just change one word in first table code and then a bit of copy and paste.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Actually, while you get an error meesage from longtable, it appears to work.  I would need to test it on a longer tabular to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

This uses supertabular instead of longtable with paracol.  The starred version numbers the pages normally (as opposed to having two page ones etc.).

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,paper=a4,fontsize=10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

        
\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}[1]*{2}
%Table 1        
\begin{supertabular}{cp{3cm}p{4cm}p{4cm}}
&\multicolumn{3}{c}{TEXTS}\\
&&&\\
a & Chinese & Sogdian  & Syriac \\
& Chinese & Sogdian  & Syriac \\
& Chinese & Sogdian  & Syriac \\
b & Chinese & Sogdian  & Syriac \\
& Chinese & Sogdian  & Syriac \\
& [...] & [...]  & [...] \\
\end{supertabular}

\lipsum[1-6]

\switchcolumn
%Table 2        
    \begin{supertabular}{cp{3cm}p{4cm}p{4cm}}
    &\multicolumn{3}{c}{TRANSLATIONS}\\
    &&&\\
    a & English 1 & English 2 & English 3 \\
    & English 1 & English 2 & English 3 \\
    & English 1 & English 2 & English 3 \\
    b & English 1 & English 2 & English 3 \\
    & English 1 & English 2 & English 3 \\
    & [...] & [...]  & [...] \\
    \end{supertabular}
    
    \lipsum[1-6]
\end{paracol}
        
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or is it two pages one?